# Where to find an official example of `hibernate.cfg.xml`?

Tags: hibernate

Couldn't find it in both the [Hibernate Getting Started Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/quickstart/html_single/) and the [Hibernate ORM User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html).
Though there's an example of `persistence.xml` [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/quickstart/html_single/#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic-config).

I know I can easily google it but I want an official version.

Answer (score 0):

Found it the following way.
In the [Hibernate Getting Started Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/quickstart/html_single/) there's a link to the [materials](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/quickstart/html_single/hibernate-tutorials.zip).
In this zip-file, there are several projects where `hibernate.cfg.xml` may be found.